# How can I view google drive pdf file in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api, flutter-getx

I want to view the google drive pdf files in a flutter app. Can anyone help me with how can I view the google drive pdf file? I am using the below code:

```
SfPdfViewer.network('https://drive.google.com/file/d/${controller.fileId}/view'))
```

Comment: You want it to open in the google drive web app?

Comment: No I want to open google drive file in flutter app

Comment: You will need to download the file from Google drive and then display it in your flutter app once its been downloaded then.

Comment: Without download I can't show it?

Comment: How else are you going to access it?  The data needs to be downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

How to create a link to a document (image, PDF…) stored in Google Drive

Share de document in Drive to anyone and copy the link and paste it to a Doc. It should look like this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14rJsPPx7hinj254H6jbb9MbmnagquWWti21vbsheP2pw4hZB4/view?usp=sharing

2. Extract your file ID (the alphanumeric between d/ and /view… In this example is:
   14rJsPPx7hinj254H6jbb9MbmnagquWWti21vbsheP2pw4hZB4
3. Add the file ID at the end of this URL:
   https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=
4. Now you have the proper link to your file (image, pdf…):
   https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=14rJsPPx7hinj254H6jbb9MbmnagquWWti21vbsheP2pw4hZB4

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).